# Cross-slope of a trail in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, slope, width

I am trying to make an accessible map that includes the typical and maximum slope and the typical and maximum cross slope.  I understand how to determine the elevation profile of the trail, but it is the cross slope (across the width of the trail) that is giving me problems.  I would like to end up with a table like this to accompany my map:

[image]

Comment: Can you just run the same process across transects? obviously doing them along the whole trail to get a representative sample

Comment: Trails on maps are typically visualised as lines on a map, for example a dotted line. Lines have zero width. So creating a slope _across_ a trail which has zero width would seem  impossible to me. Your trail data needs a width, does your data have such characteristics?

Comment: The slope of the trail is the rise/run between the nodes of the line(trail).  Wouldn't the cross slope just be the value of a slope raster generated from your surface model?  Use line statistics to get the descriptive statistic of your choice along that line.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/line-statistics.htm